# defineGetter & defineSetter on CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a fake style named `myColor` on all elements. When setting `myColor` style on the element, the actual `color` should be set with the same value. The apparent way of doing this is to use `__defineSetter__` and `__defineGetter__` on `CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype`.

Here is my implementation http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/jJ2GC/ and the expected result is once clicked **SetMyColor** button, the color of the text changed to red and show me "Set color to: red". However, the setter is not invoked as expected.

**== Updated ==**

On different browsers (webkit/mozilla/msie), they use different prefixed style names for non-standard styles. For example, Chrome uses `webkitTransition`, Firefox uses `mozTransition` and MSIE use `msTransition`. However, I want apps that use `msTransition` can run correctly on Chrome with `webkitTransition` without modification.

My question is:

1. Why my setter is not invoked?
2. How to implement such fake style?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Use a CSS compiler. So just use `transition` and re-compile it to all the browser extensions. As for bolting transitions on using `.style` in javascript just use a function that adds all the browser extensions. (A function that's not a getter/setter)

Comment: @Raynos I don't want to modify the source code of the app since I have many such apps. Instead, I want to fake APIs by JS so that they can work well on Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it works in latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with host objects and there's no guarantee they will behave like native JavaScript objects. The ECMAScript specification specifically states that host objects are not subject to the same rules as native objects. Current browser implementations vary and older versions of IE do not provide prototypes for host objects at all, so I would strongly advise against trying to do this. Use wrapper objects for your DOM elements instead.

Comment: Presumably the reason the setter doesn't work is because the host object has a catch all for all property names and injects them into the style object if they are a valid css style property.

Comment: Any other workaround to implement such features? I just want my apps working on the latest browsers (Chrome/MSIE 9+ etc).